# Converting jQuery Validation to ASP.NET MVC Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 columns to enter in UI.  How to give Regular Expression based on those 2 columns for Error Message and Condition in ASP.NET MVC3?

The Condition which is in jQuery, I am migrating to MVC3 Side:

```
if (((new Date(Date.parse($("#hupUnempBftsEndDate").val()) - Date.parse($("#hupUnempBftsBeginDate").val()))) / 86400000) < 0) {
  validationSummary = validationSummary + "! End Date of Unemployment Benefits can't be prior to Effective Date of Unemployment Benefits. \n";
```

.NET code:

```
public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [MVC Foolproof Validation](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which provides additional attributes or simply write your own custom attribute:

```
[Required]
public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }

[Required]
[GreaterThan("BeginDate")]
public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
```

Another possibility is to use [FluentValidation.NET](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) which [integrates](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) really nicely with ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in writing your own custom validation with both server and client side validation using DataAnnotations and jQuery, I wrote a [blog article about this](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/)